# Javafx: adding an image : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, javafx

Here I m trying to create a TicTacToe board but the 
code is throwing exceptions
It was showing invalid url when i used absolute path so i changed it
but it still shows invalid url or resource not found while the image definitely exists.

package sample;

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                int random = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
                if (random != 2) {
                    String image = "file:///C:/Anime/A.pics/a1.jpg";
                    if(random>0){
                        image = "file:///C:/Anime/A.pics/a1.jpg";
                    }
                    else{
                        image = " file:///C:/Anime/A.pics/a2.jpg";
                    }
                    pane.add(new ImageView(new Image(image)), j, i);
                }
            }
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 150, 150);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application.launch(args);

    }

}
```

Terminal:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1107)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:617)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:39)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1099)
    ... 11 more
```

Help me how to fix this??

Comment: Assuming not a typo when posting here, `" file:///C:/Anime/A.pics/a2.jpg"` has an erroneous space at the start.

Comment: Just a headsup: `InvocationTargetException` is **never** the actual cause of your issue. You always need to look further down the `StackTrace` and find the `Caused by:` entries.

Comment: Thanks Slaw It was the problem